# How to enable picture-in-picture mode in ReactPlayer?

Tags: reactjs, react-player, picture-in-picture

I'm new to reactjs. Here, I'm trying to add a **picture-in-picture** mode in **ReactPlayer**. I have searched and I found the **npm install react-use-pip** package, I run the below sample code of this package separately, and it's working fine. But, when I insert this code into my project code it's not working and throughs an error.

*error*: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLocaleLowerCase')

I have further doubts, Please clarify

1. Is this package will work only for the video component?
2. Can we use this package with **ReactPlayer**?
3. If we can use this package with ReactPlayer means, then what is the meaning of the error and why does it come?
4. Is there another way to add picture-in-picture and is any other package to add it?

*package name*: **npm install react-use-pip**

*Sample code*:

```js
import usePictureInPicture from 'react-use-pip'
function VideoPlayer() {
const videoRef = useRef(null)
const {
    isPictureInPictureActive,
    isPictureInPictureAvailable,
    togglePictureInPicture,
  } = usePictureInPicture(videoRef)
return(
<div className="App">
      <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted controls loop width="100%">
        <source src="video-sample.mp4" />
      </video>
      {isPictureInPictureAvailable && (
        <button
          onClick={() => togglePictureInPicture(!isPictureInPictureActive)}
        >
          {isPictureInPictureActive ? 'Disable' : 'Enable'} Picture in Picture
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
)
}
```

I'm Using the ReactPlayer component. Here, playerRef is reference variable

```js
<ReactPlayer
            url="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/big_buck_bunny_1080p.mp4"
            width={width}
            height={height}
            ref={playerRef}
/>
```

Comment: the `pip` tag is the python package manager. I am sure you wanted `picture-in-picture`. Make sure you read the tag description of acronyms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-player has a `pip` prop.
If you change `pip` to true, the video will go into picture-in-picture mode.

Something like this:

```
const Player = () => {
  const [pipMode, setPipMode] = useState(false);

  const enablePip = () => {
    setPipMode(true);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ReactPlayer
        url="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/big_buck_bunny_1080p.mp4"
        width={width}
        height={height}
        pip={pipMode}
      />
      <button onClick={EnablePip}>Toggle PIP</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

No need for react-use-pip